# For Astro.js, how to access frontmatter variables in ld+json schema.org SEO JSON?

Tags: javascript, astrojs

I have an Astro.js component called 'PageSEO' to use for SEO info for my webpages.

Pages will have title, description, an image URL, a canonical URL, and some addition info.

Here is the code of my PageSeo.astro file:

```
---
var { title, image, description, url } = Astro.props
---

<script type="application/ld+json">
  { 
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "name": {title},
    "image": {image},
    "url": {url}
  }
</script>
```

The variable info comes into the front matter fine, but it doesn't make it into the ld+json script.

I've tried the `data-title` + `this.dataset.title` and the `define:vars={{}}` method. Both failed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`define:vars` doesn't work because it assumes the `<script>` is Javascript and creates an immediately invoked function with `const` variables

Instead you can use the [`set:html`](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/directives-reference/#sethtml) directive with a template literal

```
<script type="application/ld+json" set:html={`
  { 
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "name": ${title},
    "image": ${image},
    "url": ${url}
  }
`}/>
```

**EDIT**: this could be improved using `JSON.stringify()`

```
<script type="application/ld+json" set:html={JSON.stringify({ 
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebPage",
    name: title,
    image,
    url
})}/>
```

Comment: Weird!!! I can't tell what that's doing at all, but it works. Will click that link to learn more.